# How to add event listeners with RevoGrid JSX Custom content render?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tsx

I'm using `revo-grid` with `Vue` and [TSX custom cell content renderer](https://revolist.github.io/revogrid/guide/jsx.template.html). I tried to add mouse and keyboard events to template elements. However react-style event listeners are not working in TSX. Is there any way to add event listeners to template elements?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you provide a [mre] based on your current attempt?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? You're right that the JSX syntax is a bit different than regular Vue

https://github.com/vuejs/jsx#directives

```
<input vOn:click={this.newTodoText} />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in revo-grid.

Answer (score 0):

It seems RevoGrid is using JSX to build layout only and does not manage event listeners. It just ignores any non-standard HTML attributes. So I came up with  using render functions instead of JSX.